# Windows Trekstor tablet, can't boot from any device

Tags: windows, boot

I have a very weird problem.
I have a Trekstor Surftab Wintron 10.1 tablet that had Windows 8 installed and won't boot anymore due to some bootloader error. I don't care about recovering Windows I just want to access the internal storage and recover the files.

In this BIOS settings I disabled secure boot. NOTHING will boot from this tablet.
I tried:

1. ubuntu
2. lubuntu
3. windows 7 dvd (via usb drive)
4. windows 8 dvd
5. windows 10 dvd
6. efi shell -> cannot see internal storage, maybe because is NTFS?

All I get while booting those OSes is a black screen with a dash.
Do you know why this is happening?

BTW while using ubuntu USB I don't see the device in the booting option but I have to choose "boot from file" and manually select the .efi file from EFI/BOOT.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this can help:
https://www.hardreset.info/devices/trekstor/trekstor-surftab-twin-116/boot-mode/

I've tried on a 10.1 holding Power+VolumeUp to see the Boot Menu and it works. ;)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.